# Block JavaScript Using Tampermonkey NOT WORKING?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to disable one external javascript file from loading when I view a website.  I'm using "Tampermonkey" with Google Chrome.

Here's what I tried:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var d = document;
  var scripts = d.getElementsByTagName('script'); //ARRAY 
  window.alert('script tags found:' + scripts.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var s = scripts[i].src; //String of src tag.
    if (s.indexOf('templates/base/assets/js/jquery.countdown.min.js') != -1) {
      window.alert("found: " + scripts[i].src);
      scripts[i].setAttribute('src', '');
      window.alert("src=" + scripts[i].src);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `window.onload` method on your script. From [`MDN window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, **scripts**, links and sub-frames 
>   have finished loading

So when `onload` callback function from tampermonkey is called, it's too late since the `js` from the website is already loaded.

I'm not a tampermonkey expert however to achieve your goal seems that the way to do it is using the [`// @run-at`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) directive. The documentation explains that this directive defines the moment the script is injected.

So in your case remove `window.onload` from your script and try adding the directive with for example `document-start`:

```
// ==UserScript==
...
// @run-at document-start
// @match        http://...
...
// ==/UserScript==

var d = document;
var scripts = d.getElementsByTagName('script'); //ARRAY 
window.alert('script tags found:' + scripts.length);
...
```

Hope it helps,